# Predicate<? super X>.and(Predicate<? super X>) is not applicable for the argument Predicate<? super X>

Tags: java, generics, javafx, predicate

I have to perform `and()` on my business objects that implement `Predicate<MoneyOperation>`.

Code where problem occurs is the line with `and()` call:

```
        Predicate<? super MoneyOperation> predicate =
           new MoneyOperationDateWithRadioButtonsPredicate(newv, 
                  thisDayRdBtn.getValue(), date);

        filteredData.setPredicate(filteredData.getPredicate().and(predicate));
```

Error:

```
The method and(Predicate<? super capture#14-of ? super MoneyOperation>) 
in the type Predicate<capture#14-of ? super MoneyOperation> is not applicable 
for the arguments (Predicate<capture#15-of ? super MoneyOperation>)
```

Although when I pass `predicate` to `setPredicate()` without calling `and()` compiler does not raise any errors.

`MoneyOperationDateWithRadioButtonsPredicate` class:

```
public class MoneyOperationDateWithRadioButtonsPredicate extends MoneyOperationFieldPredicate<LocalDate> { ... }
```

`MoneyOperationFieldPredicate` class:

```
public abstract class MoneyOperationFieldPredicate<T> implements Predicate<MoneyOperation> { ... }
```

Comment: Problem is that your first `Predicate<? super MoneyOperation>` uses a wildcard, i.e. an unnamed generic parameter. Taking at the look at [`Predicate#and(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html), the `Predicate` passed in as an argument must have generic type `? super T`, whereby `T` is the generic parameter of the first `Predicate` (which is an anonymous parameter) so... this won't work (since both parameters do not have any connection except `super MoneyOperation`). I would recommend to drop the `? super`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a limitation of the type system, because Java doesn't use the fact that `Predicate` has no producer methods (in the sense of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/3788176)) to handle the type differently.

Consider two `List<? super Integer>` instances: you can't do `list1.addAll(list2)`, for the same reason that you can't do `predicate1.and(predicate2)` here: that is guarding against the fact that `list1` might be a `List<Integer>`, whereas `list2` is a `List<Object>`: you shouldn't add Objects to a list that you expect only to contain Integers.

That is an actual problem for `List`s, because `List` has producer methods (e.g. `List.get(int)`), i.e. methods that are meant to give you instances of a particular type. `Predicate` only has consumer methods (one, to be exact, `Predicate.test<T>`), so there is no situation in which a `Predicate` would give you an object of an unexpected type.

However, the compiler does not consider whether a class has no producer methods (or no consumer methods): it assumes both are present (indeed, they could be present on subclasses), and so it prevents you from doing this. Annoying, maybe, but that's how it is.

The easiest way is to construct a lambda to explicitly test the two predicates:

```
setPredicate(a -> predicate1.test(a) && predicate2.test(b))
```

You may be able to use this one weird trick:

```
setPredicate(Stream.of(predicate1, predicate2).map(a -> a).reduce(Predicate::and))
```

But I have never quite been satisfied whether that works by specification, or by quirk of implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here are the captures. Let's just see what those constrains mean:

`Predicate<? super MoneyOperation>` is a predicate that can take a `MoneyOperation` or maybe it's super class and returns a boolean.
This means it can be a `Predicate<Object>` that takes an `Object` and returns a boolean.

Now there is a potential problem:
Let's assume that `MoneyOperation` extends `GenericOperation` and implements `SomeInterface`.
The first `Predicate<? super MoneyOperation>` might in fact be a `Predicate<GenericOperation>` and the second `Predicate<? super MoneyOperation>` a `Predicate<SomeInterface>`.  (The Java compiler can't tell)
Passing a `MoneyOperation` to both of them is fine, but combining them would require restricting it's type to `Predicate<MoneyOperation>`. While this would be fine for `Predicate`, it might not be for other cases.

And that's why Java doesn't allow this.
Use `Predicate<MoneyOperation>` if you know it is one.

Comment: I would add that you can convert a `Predicate<? super T>` to a `Predicate<T>` by assigning a method reference to a variable: `Predicate<T> p = lowerBoundedPredicate::test;`.